# django login without password

Tags: django, authentication

I'm looking for a way how to login without password. During create new user I noticed that, password field has default value empty, but not null. How can I do login with empty password? Because not all user need to have password set.

models.py

```
class user(AbstractUser):
```

database:

```
| username | password       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A        |                |
| B        | 123            |
```

views.py

```
user = authenticate(request, username='A', password='')

if user is not None:
     login(request, user)
     return redirect('index')
```

Comment: You can not using `login` method if want to remove password request, it is part of authenticatation in django

Answer (score 0):

Derive [a custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) from the default backend (`django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`) that allows authentication without a password for the users that are eligible for it, and set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to point to that class.

Then your views, or whatever calls `authenticate()`, will work out of the box.